# IE 7/8 / Chrome $(window).load problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

My site is runnin fine on mac ff/safari. On pc ie 7/8 and chrome I get an error $ is not defined relating to

```
$(window).load(function (){}
```

Can anyone suggest a workaround. I chose to use window.(load) over (document).ready as I am loading in some big background images and would like them to load at the start rather than risk loading delays later.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the jquery library being loaded in IE? Run fiddler and see if you are getting any errors. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: If the error is that "$" is not defined, then it has nothing to do with how your image initialization is being done.

Comment: What do your `<script>` tags look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- make sure jQuery is loaded on your page

  ```
  if(typeof jQuery === 'undefined'){
      alert('no jQuery :(');
  }
  ```
- make sure the `$` is available and assigned correctly

  ```
  (function($){
      $(document).ready(function(){
      });
  })(jQuery);
  ```

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { });` ;) or just `jQuery(function($) { });` No need for an extra closure :)

Comment: @Nick: well, maybe OP don't want directly call `.ready()`. What about `$.fn.plugin = ...` for instance, using `$`.

Comment: The plugin would be in the page...why? :)  Plugins should themselves **never** rely on `$`, but all of this is beside the point, we know exactly what he's trying to call, `$(window).load()`.  That wouldn't work in any browser if he had a problem with `$` like this, it's more likely he has malformed `<script>` tags.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your quick responses.Seems the pc I'm working on dropped internet connection. I now using local version and $(window).load is working/ Although now ie reports invalid argument in the jquery-1.4.2.min.js line:144 Char:219 

Thanks Again (oh and the OP is a she ;))
?!

Comment: @user386312: that error seems to have another origin if `$(window).load()` is working now, should maybe another post or edit it here.